# Linux. SOL_NETLINK not defined

Tags: linux, sockets

I was trying to use SOL_NETLINK in setsockopt in Linux, and got an error saying that SOL_NETLINK is not defined although in included the socket.h file.

Googled for some answers and saw people redefine SOL_NETLINK in their own files due to "Linux header file confusion".

Any explanation for that?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a workaround, but if you see [the Linux kernel](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.109/source/include/linux/socket.h#L314) `SOL_NETLINK` is always defined as 270:

```
#define SOL_NETLINK 270
```

You can just replace the constant with the value and it should work without any issue.

Answer (score -2):

I just compile-checked this code on a raspbian PI, and it compiles without any warnings.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        printf ("SOL_SOCKET=%d\n", SOL_SOCKET);
        return 0;
}
```